# My page don't' work properly on dark mode how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have This simple website that i need to make it change from light theme to dark theme, the light theme works fine, but the dark theme only changes its button properly because when i click in the button to change the "body" elements should change its class from "light-theme" to "dark-theme", instead it changes to "light-theme dark-theme"
here's HTML
`

```
<body class="light-theme">
    <h1>Task List</h1>
    <p id="msg">Current tasks:</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="list">Add visual styles</li>
      <li class="list">add light and dark themes</li>
      <li>Enable switching the theme</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">Dark</button>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to view the full site</noscript>
```

`Heres CSS`

```
:root {
  --green: #00FF00;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --black: #000000;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  color: var(--btnFontColor);
  background-color: var(--btnBg);
}

.btn:focus {
  outline-style: none;
}

body {
  background: var(--bg); 
}

ul {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

li {
  list-style: circle;
}

.list {
  list-style: square;
}

.light-theme {
  --bg: var(--green);
  --fontColor: var(--black);
  --btnBg: var(--black);
  --btnFontColor: var(--white);
}

.dark-theme{
  --bg: var(--black);
  --fontColor: var(--green);
  --btnBg: var(--white);
  --btnFontColor: var(--black);
}
```

`and heres JavaScript`

```
'use strict';
const switcher = document.querySelector('.btn');

switcher.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme')

  var className = document.body.className;
  if(className == "light-theme") {
    this.textContent = "Dark";
  } else {
    this.textContent = "Light";
  }
  console.log('current class name: ' + className);
});
```

`

I tried to change some things in css but later found that the problem might be in the javascript, but my code is exactly as the code in my course is.

Answer (score 0):

> when i click in the button to change the "body" elements should change its class from "light-theme" to "dark-theme", instead it changes to "light-theme dark-theme"

That's indeed true - your JS code is only toggling the class `"dark-theme"` and does nothing with the `"light-theme"` class.

So a simple fix would be to toggle *both* classes:

```
switcher.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme')
  document.body.classList.toggle('light-theme'); // add this line

  var className = document.body.className;
  if(className == "light-theme") {
    this.textContent = "Dark";
  } else {
    this.textContent = "Light";
  }
  console.log('current class name: ' + className);
});
```

But you could simplify your code because you really don't need 2 classes here. If light theme is the default, just remove the `light-theme` class and all its CSS rules, and apply those to `body` instead. The `.dark-theme` rules will override these when the class is set, but not otherwise.